# MySQL select result of particular column replaced by result of another

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 tables:

- Users
- Tasks

each `Task` has column with `firstname+lastname` of `user` saved in it. However, I don't think this is very good solution.
What I think would be much better is saving `id` of `user` into `Tasks`.

The problem is that I can easily do that, but how would I go about using `SELECT` query?

I would need some kind of query that would `SELECT` all rows from `Tasks` and when done, do a sequence of queries which replace each user id with his/her firstname and lastname for display purposes.

The problem is that I have no idea how would that query look like.

Comment: You need to use join in your query.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya how would I use such query if I am doing `SELECT * FROM 'Tasks'`?

Comment: You need to change query to do join with user table. Something like `SELECT t.*, CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname)  FROM Tasks t JOIN Users u ON t.userid = u.id` I also suggest you read more about join in MySQL.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I was able to execute it, however what it basically does is simply adds another column with result of CONCAT. However, what I really need is the result of of `t.userid` to be replaced with `u.id`

Comment: Youth need to select individual columns of tasks table and do not include userid column in it. `SELECT t.col1,t.col2, t.col3, CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) as userid ..... `

Comment: okay, I understand that. What I was curious about is to know whether there is a way to do such thing without selecting individual columns and writing all column names but instead simply do `SELECT *` and then specify what column I need to be replaced. Writing all columns that I need by hand is not very practical since if the table is somehow changed in the future, then I would need to change code as well

Comment: @username0: "if the table is somehow changed in the future, then I would need to change code as well" -- only if you need the additional columns. But then you had to change the code anyway (unless you just blindly dump everything in the result).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view, defined however you want, then you can select * from the view.

So something like (stack is my database name)

```
create view stack.taskAndUser as
select concat(u.firstName, ' ', u.lastName) as userName, t.*
from stack.user u join stack.task t on t.user = u.id;
```

Then you can do your lookup

```
select * from stack.taskAndUser;
```

This will include the user id being stored in task, you can change your view to omit it, but you would have to write a more detailed select statement when creating the view instead of select *.